# ScrollView Navigation title not showing in preview

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am following some tutorial and open a simple View with image a navigation title. Issue is on simulator its showing title but on preview I cant see it.

My code

```
struct AnimalDetailView: View {
    let animal: Animal
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
            VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 20) {
                // HERO IMAGE
                Image(animal.image)
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                
            } //: VSTACK
            .navigationBarTitle("Learn about \(animal.name)", displayMode: .inline)
        } //: SCROLL
    }
}
```

Here is the preview and simulator image

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This happens because the `AnimalDetailView` is not in a `NavigationView` hierarchy in the preview. Thus it displays as it is the only view present. `.navigationBarTitle()` only work when it is inside a `NavigationView`. Wrapping the `AnimalDetailView` in a `NavigationView` will display the title.

```
struct AnimalDetailView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        NavigationView {
            AnimalDetailView(animal: ...)
        }
    }
}
```

If you also want the back button to appear, you can wrap the `AnimalDetailView` in a always true `NavigationLink`.

```
struct AnimalDetailView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(isActive: .constant(true)) {
                AnimalDetailView(animal: ...)
            } label: {
                Text("")
            }
        }
    }
}
```